# Facebook Graph API stopped recognizing publish_action scope

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

I'm trying to upgrade an integration with the Facebook Graph API from version 1 to version 2.0, but I'm facing a problem: The permission `publish_actions` is not being shown in the dialog for granting.

I'm doing it manually (without the JS SDK).

PHP code:

```
header('Location: https://www.facebook.com/v2.0/dialog/oauth?client_id='.$appID.'&redirect_uri='.urlencode($callBackUrl).'&scope=publish_actions,offline_access');
exit(0);
```

Does anyone know what is happening? I've been looking for a solution for hours. As I already said, I had a working app at the Facebook from the previous version, and the Facebook API didn't show me any alert.

I assume that all configurations are correct, or at least they seem to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, the Facebook requests reviewing your app when it uses non-basic permissions like "publish_action". If you need to use these permissions, you will need to submit your app to be reviewed by Facebook's team. Only after that the permission will be shown to your app users.

For submit your app, access your app at https://developers.facebook.com/apps/, and after clicking at your app button, click at the button "Status & Review" at the left menu, fill the form and submit it. Within 5 business days you will be notified about the reviewing result.

Another thing that has changed is that non-basic permissions are only shown to the user after he approves the basic permissions.

Furthermore it's allowed to use your own user to test the app (with all permissions, including non-basic's) before submit it.